# Excel: How to sort data based on a column using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sort data in the screenshot based on the "sale" column using formula, so that "B" is achieved.
[image: sorting data]

Comment: Record a macro while performing the sort.

Comment: Just sort on Column C descending using the inbuilt sort functionality i.e. press the sort button and ensure all columns covered.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight your data: Click on data tab -> click on sort -> set sort by to Sales -> sort on select values -> set Order to largest to smallest

Or using macro (recorded above):

```
    Range("A1:C5").Select
    Range("C5").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C5")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed advice to just use a VBA macro, since it's easier to extend it's range when need values are added. However, for anyone wondering if it is possible without any VBA scripts at all: **it indeed is** (by adding two or three additional columns).

```
  | K         | L           | M      | N     | O    | P
--+-----------+-------------+--------+-------+------+----
1 | Unsorted: | Customer Id | Name   | Sales | temp | KEY
2 |           | 222         | John   | 30    | †¹   | 1
3 |           | 333         | Frank  | 90    | †¹   | 2
4 |           | 350         | Joe    | 30    | †¹   | 3
5 |           | 451         | Daniel | 60    | †¹   | 4
```

†¹: The formula in cell `O2` is `=N2+P2/1000000`; in cell `O3` it's `=N3+P3/1000000`; etc.

```
  | Q       | R   | S           | T    | U    
--+---------+-----+-------------+------+------
1 | Sorted: | KEY | Customer Id | Name | Sales
2 |         | †²  | †³          | †⁴   | †⁵
3 |         | †²  | †³          | †⁴   | †⁵
4 |         | †²  | †³          | †⁴   | †⁵
5 |         | †²  | †³          | †⁴   | †⁵
```

†²: The formula in cell `R2` is `=VLOOKUP(LARGE(O2:O5;P2);O2:P5;2;FALSE)`; in cell `R3` it's `=VLOOKUP(LARGE(O2:O5;P3);O2:P5;2;FALSE)`; etc.
†³: The formula in cell `S2` is `=INDEX(L2:L5;R2)`; in cell `S3` it's `=INDEX(L2:L5;R3)`; etc.
†⁴: The formula in cell `T2` is `=INDEX(M2:M5;R2)`; in cell `T3` it's `=INDEX(M2:M5;R3)`; etc.
†⁵: The formula in cell `U2` is `=INDEX(N2:N5;R2);` in cell `U3` it's `=INDEX(N2:N5;R3)`; etc.

**General explanation:**

The columns `L` through `N` contain the unsorted data that we want to sort based on column `N` in this case. Column `P` contains subsequent integers starting at `1`, which will be used in our formulas as an index.

The column `O` contains a temp value. This temp value is used in combination with the index divided by a million to distinguish duplicated values in the column we want to sort on (`N` in this case), so each value we want to sort on is unique. If the column we want to sort on will never have any duplicated values, the `temp` column `O` won't be necessary, and the formulas can be modified a bit to account for this.

In this case, the `temp`/`O` column will contain the following values:

```
O
----
temp
30.000001
90.000002
30.000003
60.000004
```

The column `S` will use a vertical lookup. It first gets the `k-1`'th largest value in the `temp`/`O` column, where the `P` column is used for this value `k`. Then it will look for this `k-1`'th largest value of the `O` column inside the `O2:P6` matrix, and get its row, after which the second column is used for the result (hence the `;2;FALSE)` in the `VLOOKUP`-formula. So now we have our sorted `KEY`/`R` column.

And we use this `KEY` as an index to get the corresponding values in the column `L` through `N`, to put those sorted in the columns `S` through `V`.

If you would now modify a value in the `N` column (for example, `60` to `160`), the columns will automatically be sorted thanks to the formulas.